# Scheduling bridge games with restrictions on partnerships

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This question is suggested by problem 1.3.43 in Douglas B. West's "Introduction to Graph Theory."  To paraphrase, the game of bridge is played by two partnerships of two players each.  $14$ people arrive at a bridge club that has the rule that no game can be played if any two of the four players have previously been partners.  They play until each person has partnered $4$ other players, and then they manage to play $6$ more games, but then the club rule prevents forming any more games.  At this point, a $15$th person shows up.  Show that it is now possible to play at least one more game.

I can do the problem, but I am curious about the bounds on the number of games that can be played until a blockage occurs.  Consider the $14$ players as the vertices of a graph $G$, with an edge between any two players who have not been partners, so that we start with $K_{14}$.  To schedule a game, choose $4$ players who induce a $K_4$ subgraph $H$, and delete two disjoint edges of $H$ from $G$.  Continue until $G$ has no $K_4$.  What are the maximum and minimum number of times we can do this?

Since there are $91$ edges to begin with, and each game deletes two edges, there cannot be $>45$ games, but this must be a gross over-estimate.  By Turan's theorem, any graph with $14$ vertices and more than $65$ edges contains a $K_4$ so we must be able to play $13$ games, no matter how badly we schedule them.

I've done about $100,000$ experiments, choosing games at random, and the values have ranged from $17$ to $29$.  I haven't been able to think of any way to improve these bounds analytically, nor to construct schedules with high or low values manually.  I'd be interested in any suggestions on how to approach either or both of these.

Solution to the textbook problem:

> They've played $20$ games so the graph has $51$ edges remaining.  By Mantel's theorem, the graph contains a $K_3$.  These $3$ people can form a game with the newcomer.

Comment: Very interesting question, esp. since I play bridge!  (Even though this really has nothing to do with bridge, I know...  :) ) Anyway you wrote "nor to construct schedules with high or low values manually." -- What do you mean by that?  Esp. on the low end, you mean you want to construct a schedule (in some systemic way i.e. not using the randomized algo) that provably ends after a very small no. of games?  Or do you mean you can't think of any systemic way to construct a schedule at all (regardless of high / medium / low values)?